# Tableau - Calculate profit when cost and revenue are in same column

Tags: tableau-api

I want to calculate profit when cost and revenue are in the same column. For example:

```
 item   account_category   balance
   x                cost         5
   x                cost         5
   x             revenue        12
   y                cost         8
   y             revenue         7
```

So, in Tableau, I'd like to have calculation that gives me profit both in terms of absolute dollars (i.e., `revenue` - `cost`) and percentage of revenue (i.e., (`revenue` - `cost`)/ `revenue`). I'd then like to slice / dice by columns like `item`.

I'm not even sure where to start; I've tried table calculations with no success.

Comment: So you are trying to do `12-5 and 7-8` and `(12-5)/12 and (7-8)/7`... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but to be clear, it would be `(12-5-5)` and `(7-8)`, then  `(12-5-5)/12` and `(7-8)/7`...since its would be aggregated by `item` in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profit:

```
SUM(IIF([account_category] = "revenue",[balance],NULL))
-
SUM(IIF([account_category] = "cost",[balance],NULL))
```

% of Revenue:

```
(
    SUM(IIF([account_category] = "revenue",[balance],NULL))
    -
    SUM(IIF([account_category] = "cost",[balance],NULL))
)
/
SUM(IIF([account_category] = "revenue",[balance],NULL))
```

To create the view:

[image]

The level in the view does not matter (i.e. here is total profit, % of Revenue):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I figured out a workaround which essentially did the same thing with two helper columns, but I like your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Steps:

Place `Item` and `Account Category` on Rows and then uncheck `Show Header` of account category.

Add balance to the sheet and apply table calculation for `difference` and execution should be `Pane Down` Or Create a calcualted field and use below code:

```
ZN(SUM([Balance])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Balance])), -1)
```

Now create one more formula and use below code for Percentage Calculation

```
[Profit]/SUM([Revenue])
```

Filter the rows that are `null`.

Your report would be like below:

[image]

I can share the report if you need.